# Poco::Thread hangup on multiple start and join in quick succession

Tags: c++, multithreading, poco-libraries

I'm stuck with an issue using Poco::Thread. This Code hangs at around 4K iterations. Built with GCC 4.6.1 for QNX5, POCO_VERSION 0x01040602.

```
#include "Poco/Thread.h"
using namespace Poco;

class SignalAdapter: public Runnable
{
public:
    SignalAdapter()
    {}

    virtual void run()
    {
        //printf( "This is thread %d\n", Thread::currentTid() );
    }
};

int main() {
  Thread oThread;
  SignalAdapter oSignalAdapter{};

  for (auto i = 0; i < 1e5; ++i)
  {
      oThread.start(oSignalAdapter);
      if (oThread.isRunning())
          oThread.join();

  }
}
```

However, it works fine using PThread directly, it also works fine on Windows. I would be glad for some help.

Comment: Try removing `if (oThread.isRunning())` part. It is not needed for two reasons: you can join a thread that has already finished and, due to concurrency, the predicate may become wrong before body of the if block is executed.

Comment: @AlexeyGuseynov That is indeed a solution for my minimal example and also a good hint about the predicate. However, in my full program it crashes without the isRunning() switch. I need to rethink about it.

Comment: Now I figured out the actual problem in my full program. There I do a join before I called start. That leads to an immediate crash. Apparently, Poco does not tolerate a join with a thread, which never was started - a behavior different to pthread.

Comment: At least newer releases (starting with 1.6) should not crash if you call join() before the thread has been started. But maybe you should rethink the structure of your application, e.g., why create the thread object if you're not going to use it. Maybe using Poco::ThreadPool would be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal state of a Poco::Thread is not thread safe (atomic). You will get a race condition in `start()`, `join()` and `isRunning()` leading to thread leaks (not joining the current `Runnable`).

Using g++ with -fsanitize=thread -static-libtsan:

```
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: thread leak (pid=24366)
  Thread T1 (tid=32349, finished) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create <null> (Test+0x0000004945e7)
    #1 Poco::ThreadImpl::startImpl(Poco::Runnable&) <null> (libPocoFoundation.so.20+0x0000000f8d67)
    #2 __libc_start_main <null> (libc.so.6+0x00000002082f)

  And 11 more similar thread leaks.
```

Looking into the sources of POCO, the Poco::Event (used internally by Poco::Thread`) seems to be the problematic part of the implementation.

I suggest not to use `Poco::Thread` and use `std::thread` (C++11), instead.

Comment: Thank you for providing detailed explanation. The internally used event was my guess, too. Std::thread would be my first choice, if supported by the compiler.